# Has something happened to our custom close reasons?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, close-reasons

I'm think I'm probably being incredibly stupid here, so please feel free to point out the obvious... but I can't seem to find our custom close reasons (product or service recommendation / videography) any more:

[image]

What do I need to do to find them/get them back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the "Off Topic" reason and the custom options will appear.

Comment: Thanks. Me stupid.